# If $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = +\infty$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{\int_0^x f(s) \; ds}{x} = +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$
>
> If $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = +\infty$ and $F(x) = \int_0^x f(s) \; ds$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{F(x)}{x} = +\infty$

I thought of using mean value theorem but this would give me a $c \in ]0,x[$ and I need it to diverge.

**Edit**

I also tried l'Hôpital but for that I should have $F(x)$ diverging and this needs not be the case.

What other idea could I use here?

Comment: You could try to apply L'Hopital to $F(x)/x$.

Comment: @Winther Then do we know anything about $f (\pm \infty)$?

Comment: @xbh We know that $f(x) = x \cdot \frac{f(x)}{x}$

Comment: @Winther Oh right, stupid me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = \pm \infty.$$

Now use L'Hopital's Rule on your problem:

$$ \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac {\int_0^x f(s)~ds}{x}= \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{f(x)}{1}= \pm \infty.$$

Comment: The upper limit on the integral should be $x$ not $s$.

Comment: Why have you written “$\pm$” before $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}\cfrac{f(x)}{1}$? Actually $D\int_0^x f(s)ds=f(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ even for $x<0$. There should not be any “$\pm$” before the limit. Consequently, $$ \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac {\int_0^x f(s)~ds}{x}= \lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}\cfrac{f(x)}{1}= \pm \infty.$$